# Qt & C++: Array of function pointers with different return and parameter types

Tags: c++, qt, callback

I'm working on C++ 11, Qt 5.12. I need to store function pointers in some map or array. The point is that, these methods have differente return types and parameter types.

I've defined some simple data structures in classes. Here's an example as simple as I can:

```
class TableData
{
public:
    enum EnumFieldType
    {
        FieldType_None = 0,
        FieldType_Int,
        FieldType_QString
    };
    enum EnumFieldId
    {
        FieldId_None = 0,
        FieldId_Id,
        MaxSystemFieldId = 64
    };
int id() const;
void setId(const int _id);
QVariant getFieldValue(int _fieldId);
void setFieldValue(int _fieldId, QVariant _value)
protected:
int id_;
//Here some QMap or QVector with the function pointers
}

class EmployeeData : public TableData
{
public: 
    enum EnumFieldId
    {
        FieldId_Name = TableData::MaxSystemFieldId + 1,
        FieldId_Age
    };
   QString name() const;
   int age() const;
   void setName(const QString &_name);    
   int setAge(const Int &_age);    
protected:
    int             age_;
    QString         name_;
}
```

The idea is to create in TableData three maps:

- QMap mapFieldTypes
- QMap mapGetters
- QMap

These maps will be filled in TableData subclasses constructors. So, once an instance of subclasses is built, I can use:

```
EmployeeData  ed;
ed.setId(5);
ed.setAge(11);
ed.setName("Son Gohan");
```

Or:

```
EmployeeData ed;
ed.setField(EmployeeData::FieldId_Id, 5);
ed.setField(EmployeeData::FieldId_Age, 11);
ed.setField(EmployeeData::FieldId_Name, "Son Gohan");
```

These last calls go to TableData::SetField method, that should look into the map mapFieldTypes with the FieldId key to obtain the type of the field; then get the setter function pointer and call it with the QVariant parameter properly converted to the type requested by the setter function.

I've spent a lot of hours struggling about this, reading, looking and searching for some solution. Arrays of pointers or callbacks must be of same function type, std::function and std::bind don't solve this (arrays must be of same function type and bind uses already predefined values, etc)... I need something similar to the (void *) pointer applied to variables, but for function pointers (using the types map, I think that I can effectively cast the generic function pointer to the needed function pointer template).

Any ideas?

PD: Sorry for some code issues or typos, the real code is by far more elaborated and i've tried to simplify and ease it as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [Qt's Property System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) is the perfect solution for you:

```
class TableData : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        TableData() : QObject(), _id(0) {}

        QVariant getFieldValue(const char * fieldName) const {
            return property(fieldName);
        }

        void setFieldValue(const char * fieldName, QVariant _value) {
            setProperty(fieldName, _value);
        }

        int id() const { return _id; }

        void setId(int newID) {
            _id = newID;
            emit idChanged();
        }

    protected:
        Q_PROPERTY(int id
                   READ id
                   WRITE setId
                   NOTIFY idChanged)
        int _id;

    signals:
        void idChanged();
};
```

```
class EmployeeData : public TableData {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        EmployeeData() : TableData(), _age(-1), _name("") {}

        int age() const { return _age; }

        void setAge(int newAge) {
            _age = newAge;
            emit ageChanged();
        }

        QString name() const { return _name; }

        void setName(QString newName) {
            _name = newName;
            emit nameChanged();
        }

    protected:
        Q_PROPERTY(int age
                   READ age
                   WRITE setAge
                   NOTIFY ageChanged)
        int _age;

        Q_PROPERTY(QString name
                   READ name
                   WRITE setName
                   NOTIFY nameChanged)
        QString _name;

    signals:
        void ageChanged();
        void nameChanged();
};
```

The `void TableData::setField(const char *, QVariant);` method will call `void QObject::setProperty(const char *, QVariant);`. This last will automatically call the setter you specify in the `WRITE` property field in order to update the property value. The following three pieces of code exactly do the same thing:

Using attributes' setters:

```
EmployeeData ed;
ed.setId(5);
ed.setAge(11);
ed.setName("Son Gohan");
```

Using `void TableData::setField(const char *, QVariant);`:

```
EmployeeData ed;
ed.setField("id", 5);
ed.setField("age", 11);
ed.setField("name", "Son Gohan");
```

Using `void QObject::setProperty(const char *, QVariant);` (since your `EmployeeData` is also a `QObject`):

```
EmployeeData  ed;
ed.setProperty("id", 5);
ed.setProperty("age", 11);
ed.setProperty("name", "Son Gohan");
```

Same thing for reading attributes. Your `QVariant TableData::getField(const char *) const;` method will call `QVariant QObject::property(const char *) const;`. This last will automatically call the getter you specify in the `READ` property field in order to retrieve the property value. The following three pieces of code exactly do the same thing:

Using attributes' setters:

```
// Using the EmployeeData ed defined above
int id = ed.id();            // id == 5
int age = ed.age();          // age == 11
QString name = ed.name();    // name == "Son Gohan"
```

Using `QVariant TableData::getField(const char *) const;`:

```
// Using the EmployeeData ed defined above
int id = ed.getField("id").toInt();               // id == 5
int age = ed.getField("age").toInt();             // age == 11
QString name = ed.getField("name").toString();    // name == "Son Gohan"
```

Using `QVariant QObject::property(const char *) const;` (since your `EmployeeData` is also a `QObject`):

```
// Using the EmployeeData ed defined above
int id = ed.property("id").toInt();               // id == 5
int age = ed.property("age").toInt();             // age == 11
QString name = ed.property("name").toString();    // name == "Son Gohan"
```

Comment: es, I think this approach fits my needs. I wanted to keep TableData classes as simple as possible, but this approach and the benefits of QObject+QPropertiy meta-systems clearly surpass the cons.
I will refactor all my data structures... a bunch of work but I will be worth the effort. Thanks!!
PS: But I am still curious... ¿Would it be possible to get an array (or similar) of function pointers with different return values or parameters?
PS2: I like the care you took writing your example... thumbs up

Comment: If your class derives from QObject, you will also be able to use Qt's introspection API, with meta objects and `QMeta*` classes. It might not be function pointers just like you want, but it will still enable you to access to methods and invoke them.